# How to constrain values inside an object to keys of that same object

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
const obj: Obj = {
    a: ['b'],
    b: ['c']
}
```

How can I type `Obj` such that `a: ['b']` is allowed, but `b: ['c']` is not.

I've got this so far:

```
type Obj = {
    [key: string]: (keyof Obj)[]
}
```

But both are giving the error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDA8kmBeGBvAsAFAwkwCGqA2gOTzUC6ANEaTPFdcA0QL5FFQAngAcApukw4CxUpQDWowamgAnAJZgA5vVQAKBYJAAzCYgCUleryA)

Comment: I don't think that's possible, at least with TypeScript types at compile time. Do you have a real use case or was this discovered randomly?

Comment: I want to create a dependency injection container where the services are defined up-front in an object like this. So for instance service `a` has service `b` as a dependency, but service `b` cannot have service `c` as a dependency, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this at runtime?

Comment: Ideally I want type inference when the services are being defined, as this is an API for a public package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that creating a circular reference within a type to that type's own keys is possible. However, if you use two types, this gets much simpler:

```
type Services = 'a' | 'b'

type ServiceDependencies = {
  [key in Services]: Services[]
}

const obj: ServiceDependencies = {
  a: ['b'], 
  b: ['c'] // error
}
```

This has the nice benefit of requiring service dependencies to be explicitly defined for every Service (try adding another value to the `Services` type in [this Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOA3AlgYwgZygXigcgEM8oAffAIzwCgrRJYEV0ARCSAOwBMJ3VlMcUAN5UoUANoBrCCCjJ2DJGkwBdAFyKmmcSqoBfGqgD27DMChHyAKw1wlLNj269+WXCLEEN4vJRUAaKFEocm88VDwVKAB6aKgEeCN4fSA) - you'll get an error until you update `obj` to account for this).